# Need help converting a json string to an object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following JSON object returned from the service and I need to convert to the Directory class. How do I do that since the Directory class has the 'expanded' property that does not exist in the JSON object.  Pls. help I have tried for the past days.

Thank in advance.

```
    export class Directory {
       type: string;
       name: string;
       expanded: false;
       directories: Directory[];
       files: File[];
    }
    export class File {
       type: string;
       name: string;
       fileExtension: string;
       size: string;
       lastModified: string;
       downloadUrl: string;
    }
```

```
[
    {
        "type": "directory",
        "name": "DIR A",
        "directories": [],
        "files": [
            {
                "type": "file",
                "name": "FILEN.pdf",
                "fileExtension": ".pdf",
                "size": 1000,
                "lastModified": "2020-06-17",
                "downloadUrl": "http://example.com/filename.pdf"
            },
            {
                "type": "file",
                "name": "FILEN-1.pdf",
                "fileExtension": ".pdf",
                "size": 1000,
                "lastModified": "2020-06-15",
                "downloadUrl": "http://example.com/filename-1.pdf"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "directory",
        "name": "DIR B",
        "directories": [],
        "files": [
            {
                "type": "file",
                "name": "FILEN-2.pdf",
                "fileExtension": ".pdf",
                "size": 1000,
                "lastModified": "2020-06-12",
                "downloadUrl": "http://example.com/filename-2.pdf"
            }
        ]
    }   
]
```

I tried the followings:

```
  this.api.getFileUrl().subscribe((response:any) => {
    let directory: Directory = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
  });
```

and the directory object does not have the 'expanded' property when I debugged it.  BTW, I am new in Typescript and Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have json in property named data, Just do :-

```
public directory: Omit<Directory, 'expanded'> = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this in your attempted solution...

```
this.api.getFileUrl().subscribe((response:any) => {
    //..
}
```

In order for this to be correct and fully working, that means you must have `getFileURL()` set like so...

```
this.api.getFileUrl() = from(fetch('SomeJsonPageOfYours.json')).pipe(
    switchMap(response => response.json())
)
```

If you're not getting the data structure you expect, I would look at what you're [`subscribing()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html) `this.api.getFileUrl()` with.  Are you sure you have the `.json()` calls on the `response` object?  I would look in this direction (I didn't see the code for this posted).

Answer (score 0):

Declare an interface and implement it:

```
 export interface IDirectory {
       type: string;
       name: string;
       directories: Directory[];
       files: File[];
    }
     export class Directory implements IDirectory {
       type: string;
       name: string;
       expanded: false;
       directories: Directory[];
       files: File[];
    }
```

Now use the interface type:

```
this.api.getFileUrl().subscribe((response:any) => {
    let directory: IDirectory = response;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should realize that type from TypeScript does not do anything on runtime.

Looks like `Directory` class has the ony value for `expanded`  -> `false` so we can assign this value to the response object.

So what you can do is the following:

```
// means all values except expanded
type IGetFileUrlResponse = Omit<Directory, 'expanded'>; 

this.api.getFileUrl().subscribe((response: IGetFileUrlResponse) => {
    // here we add expanded prop for valid Directory type
    let directory: Directory = {
       ...response,
       expanded: false,
    };
 });
```